# Normalize several columns to one many to many table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, many-to-many, relational-database

I want to normalize a table with data spread in multiple columns to a many to many table.

In my case, I have a `person` table with `hobby1`, `hobby2`, `hobby3`, `hobby4` string columns containing the names found in a `hobby` table. Some are empty some are not.

Currently the db design looks like this:

[image: original database design]

Currently `person_hobby` is empty.

Can you help me with the SQL query for populating the `person_hobby` table with all the strings found in the `hobby` columns related to the `hobby.name` so I can get rid of them later?

Thanks

Comment: so is your `hobby` table already populated? Also, SO is not a "write code for me"-site, so please show us your attempts on solving this yourself. (One hint is `INSERT ... SELECT`, look into the docs aka ... rtfm)

Comment: what's the point of posting my attempts if they don't work? this is a real question that could help other people with the same problem. I'm using fictional data exactly for helping with my question to other stackoverflow users.

Comment: as far as I understand it, SO provides help when you encounter a problem you can't solve by yourself. AFAIK this is very straightforward with `INSERT ... SELECT`, so as far as I am concerned, there is no problem until you show your failed attempts.

Comment: I'm not so sure that this is as straightforward as Jakumi suggests - but I do agree that it's nice to see that an attempt is made, albeit a poor one.

Comment: @Strawberry the hardest thing - I believe - is populating the `hobby` table without duplicates. after that it's 4 queries (one for each hobby field) where you inner join one hobby field with the name field and get a (person_id,hobby_id) pair.

Comment: @denoise I really hope in person_hobby the primary key is both fields together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

E.g.:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person;

CREATE TABLE person
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,hobby1 VARCHAR(15) NULL
,hobby2 VARCHAR(15) NULL
,hobby3 VARCHAR(15) NULL
,hobby4 VARCHAR(15) NULL
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person_hobby;

CREATE TABLE person_hobby
(person_id INT NOT NULL 
,hobby_id INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(person_id,hobby_id)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS hobby;

CREATE TABLE hobby
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO person VALUES
(1,'John'  ,'Reading'   ,'Cycling','Swimming',NULL),
(2,'Paul'  ,'Travelling','TV','Bird watching','Cinema'),
(3,'George','Fishing'   ,'Swimming',NULL,NULL),
(4,'Ringo',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);

INSERT INTO hobby (name) 
SELECT hobby1 FROM person WHERE hobby1 IS NOT NULL UNION 
SELECT hobby2 FROM person WHERE hobby2 IS NOT NULL UNION 
SELECT hobby3 FROM person WHERE hobby3 IS NOT NULL UNION 
SELECT hobby4 FROM person WHERE hobby4 IS NOT NULL;

INSERT INTO person_hobby
SELECT p.id 
     , h.id 
  FROM
     (
SELECT id
     , hobby1 hobby
  FROM person
 UNION
SELECT id 
     , hobby2 
  FROM person
 UNION
SELECT id 
     , hobby3
  FROM person
 UNION
SELECT id 
     , hobby4
  FROM person
     ) p
  JOIN hobby h
    ON h.name = p.hobby;

Query OK, 9 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 9  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

SELECT * FROM person_hobby;
+-----------+----------+
| person_id | hobby_id |
+-----------+----------+
|         1 |        1 |
|         1 |        4 |
|         1 |        6 |
|         2 |        2 |
|         2 |        5 |
|         2 |        7 |
|         2 |        8 |
|         3 |        3 |
|         3 |        6 |
+-----------+----------+
```

Now drop the columns from the person table.

Answer (score 0):

repeat for every hobby field (notice the `hobby1` in the `ON`-clause):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO person_hobby (person_id, hobby_id) 
     SELECT person.id, hobby.id
     FROM person
     INNER JOIN hobby ON (person.hobby1=hobby.name)
```