# ColdFusion is giving error when executing database query

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Can somebody please suggest what is wrong with this code?

```
<cfquery name="getPreviousDBentries" datasource="#application.datasource#">
    select image, image_b,
    image_c,image_d,image_e, image_f from used_listings_v2 where id = '#edit#'
</cfquery>

<cfdump var="#getPreviousDBentries#">
<cftry>
    <cfquery name="updateToNull" datasource="#application.datasource#">
        <cfif len(getPreviousDBentries.image) neq 0>
            Update used_listings_v2 SET image = NULL where id = '#edit#'
        </cfif>

        <cfif len(getPreviousDBentries.image_b) neq 0>
            Update used_listings_v2 SET image_b = NULL where id = '#edit#'
        </cfif>

        <cfif len(getPreviousDBentries.image_c) neq 0>
            Update used_listings_v2 SET image_c = NULL where id = '#edit#'
        </cfif>

        <cfif len(getPreviousDBentries.image_d) neq 0>
            Update used_listings_v2 SET image_d = NULL where id = '#edit#'
        </cfif>

        <cfif len(getPreviousDBentries.image_e) neq 0>
            Update used_listings_v2 SET image_e = NULL where id = '#edit#'
        </cfif>

        <cfif len(getPreviousDBentries.image_f) neq 0>
            Update used_listings_v2 SET image_f = NULL where id = '#edit#'
        </cfif>
    </cfquery>

<cfcatch>
<cfdump var="#cfcatch#">
</cfcatch>

</cftry>
```

I am getting correct output when the image column has some value i.e. image, image_b,image_c, image_d,image_e, image_f are not null.

But it's giving me an error saying error executing database query when image, image_b,image_c, image_d,image_e, image_f are null.

Please suggest possible solutions.

Comment: What is the error message? Is the error on one of the `cfif` lines or SQL `Update` lines

Comment: Getting an error would make sense if all the `<cfif>` conditions inside your `<cfquery>` are false.  That's because it would be like executing a `<cfquery>` with no statements inside it.  You will need an additional `<cfif>` condition outside your `<cfquery>` to test if all conditions are false and skip executing the `<cfquery>`.

Comment: @user12031119 yes correct. All of my conditions are false. However, I don't want to update the table if the condition is false. What should I do in that case?

Comment: Of course, if all the conditions are false, then no action needs to be taken.  Did you read my answer?

Comment: Sorry @user12031119, I got that now. Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you're getting an error message is because all of the `<cfif>` conditions are false, it's like executing a `<cfquery>` with no code inside of it.  So you will need to add an additional condition outside the `<cfquery>` block to test and make sure at least one of your `UPDATE` commands will execute.

```
<cfquery name="getPreviousDBentries" datasource="#application.datasource#">
    select image, image_b,
    image_c,image_d,image_e, image_f from used_listings_v2 where id = '#edit#'
</cfquery>

<cfif NOT (len(getPreviousDBentries.image) eq 0> AND 
      len(getPreviousDBentries.image_b) eq 0 AND
      len(getPreviousDBentries.image_c) eq 0 AND
      len(getPreviousDBentries.image_d) eq 0 AND
      len(getPreviousDBentries.image_e) eq 0 AND
      len(getPreviousDBentries.image_f) eq 0)>

    <cftry>
        <cfquery name="updateToNull" datasource="#application.datasource#">
            <cfif len(getPreviousDBentries.image) neq 0>
                Update used_listings_v2 SET image = NULL where id = '#edit#'
            </cfif>

            <cfif len(getPreviousDBentries.image_b) neq 0>
                Update used_listings_v2 SET image_b = NULL where id = '#edit#'
            </cfif>

            <cfif len(getPreviousDBentries.image_c) neq 0>
                Update used_listings_v2 SET image_c = NULL where id = '#edit#'
            </cfif>

            <cfif len(getPreviousDBentries.image_d) neq 0>
                Update used_listings_v2 SET image_d = NULL where id = '#edit#'
            </cfif>

            <cfif len(getPreviousDBentries.image_e) neq 0>
                Update used_listings_v2 SET image_e = NULL where id = '#edit#'
            </cfif>

            <cfif len(getPreviousDBentries.image_f) neq 0>
                Update used_listings_v2 SET image_f = NULL where id = '#edit#'
            </cfif>
        </cfquery>

        <cfcatch>
            <cfdump var="#cfcatch#">
        </cfcatch>

    </cftry>
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 0):

[@user12031119's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71129655/8895292) already explains why the error occurs. As far as the code, instead of constructing multiple queries, a single query would be more maintainable. Use a [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) statement or your database's version of [IIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to update the columns only if the value is empty. The exact syntax is dbms specific.

For example, say the image columns are all populated except for "image_d":

**Sample**

```
id  | image     | image_b    | image_c  | image_d
1   | arrow.png | up.png     | down.png | (empty string)
```

**DDL** (SQL Server)

```
CREATE TABLE used_listings_v2 
(
   id int 
   , image varchar(50)
   , image_b varchar(50)
   , image_c varchar(50)
   , image_d varchar(50)
)
;


INSERT INTO used_listings_v2 (id, image, image_b, image_c, image_d)
VALUES (1, 'arrow.png', 'up.png', 'down.png', '')
;
```

Use a CASE to check the length of the existing values, and set them to NULL only if the contain an empty string (i.e. length = 0).

```
-- Example using CASE
SET Column = CASE WHEN LEN(Column) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE Column END

-- Example using IIF
SET Column = IIF( LEN(Column) = 0, NULL, Column )
```

So this query will preserve any existing value and only update empty columns to null:

[SQL Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6ee011cf831083df6deadb14a2136a30)

```
UPDATE used_listings_v2
SET    image = CASE WHEN LEN(image) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE image END
       , image_b = CASE WHEN LEN(image_b) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE image_b END
       , image_c = CASE WHEN LEN(image_c) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE image_c END
       , image_d = CASE WHEN LEN(image_d) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE image_d END
WHERE id = 1
```

**Results**

```
id  | image     | image_b    | image_c  | image_d
1   | arrow.png | up.png     | down.png | (null)
```

*NB: In the actual cfquery, wrap the #edit# variable in [cfqueryparam](https://cfdocs.org/cfqueryparam) to help protect the query against sql injection.*

Having said that though, having a bunch of similarly named columns all storing the same thing (i.e. image, image_b, image_c, .., image_N) is **a strong indicator you need to [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) the model**. [Storing the images in rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39039184/normalize-several-columns-to-one-many-to-many-table-in-mysql) instead of columns, provides much greater flexibility and would simplify tasks like this.